# How to initialize a web plugin (DarkReader) into my html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to import the 'enable' method from the 'DarkReader' plugin. I'm not so familiar with the JavaScript plugin initialization process in an HTML document.

I opened a  tag in the ending of the  tag, the source of it directs to the plugin web hosting url.

and inside that, I tried to initialize it with this script:

````
<script src="https://unpkg.com/darkreader">

      import {
          enable as enableDarkMode,
          disable as disableDarkMode,
      } from 'darkreader';

    </script>

    <button id="tt" onclick="enableDarkMode({
          brightness: 100,
          contrast: 90,
          sepia: 10,
      });">
      CLICK
    </button>```

Can someone explain how to do that?
````

Comment: A `<script>` tag can have an `src` **or** inner text code....but not both. Use two tags. When there is an `src` the inner text is ignored

Comment: I tried this code: "<script src="https://unpkg.com/darkreader"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      
      import {
          enable as enableDarkMode,
          disable as disableDarkMode,
      } from 'darkreader';

      enableDarkMode({
          brightness: 100,
          contrast: 90,
          sepia: 10,
      });</script>" But it's still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Write it like that

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkreader/darkreader.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    DarkReader.enable({
        brightness: 100,
        contrast: 90,
        sepia: 10
        });
</script>
```